# C++ cross platform: what is my MAC address

Tags: c++, networking, cross-platform, boost-asio

Using boost, I am able to read all the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for each of my computer's NICs.

Is there similar functionality for querying the MAC address on my local machine?

I searched the boost API and the various forums, and could not find an answer other than implementing it myself and wrapping with `ifdef`.

Comment: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/MAC-Address-tp2581617p2581618.html

Comment: That's what I was referring to when I said that I found solutions that require `ifdef`. I am looking for a standard cross-platform solution

Comment: @levengli "*I am looking for a standard cross-platform solution*" - there isn't one. You need to use platform-specific functions, like `getifaddrs()` and `ioctl()` on *Nix, `GetAdaptersAddresses()` on Windows, etc